# Openpyxl: Write to an existing workbook the previous sheet was deleted

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I'm working on a function to write to an existing .xlsx file.
My environment is:
Win 10
Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
openpyxl 3.1.2
pandas 2.0.0
When I tried to write a new sheet the previous sheet disappeared

Can you please help me to see what is wrong?
Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook


def write_resolution(df, file_name, sheet_name):
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        workbook = load_workbook(file_name)
    else:
        workbook = Workbook()      
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.workbook  = workbook

    if sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
        del workbook[sheet_name]
    
    worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(sheet_name,-1)         
    worksheet=workbook.active
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    
    workbook.save(file_name)
    writer.close()
```

I tried below:

1. Initially there was no file, I wrote to sheet1, success
2. I then write to sheet2. Sheet2 is successful, but sheet1 has gone

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there would be a lot of single calls to the function opening and closing files for no good reason. It should only be necessary to create the `writer` once and write each `dataframe` to its' `sheet name`. Nor is there a need for `Openpyxl` to create the workbook.
The `Excel` file will be created by `ExcelWriter` if it doesn't already exist using `mode='w'`. If it does exist then it will be appended to using `mode='a'` so running the code again with different sheet names will add those sheets to the existing workbook.
`ExcelWriter` also has the `if_sheet_exists` parameter which can be set to `'error', 'new', 'replace', 'overlay`, the default being `error`. Since you are deleting the sheet if it already exists I have set it to 'replace'.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


def write_resolution(dfs, fn, md):
    ### 'if_sheet_exist' needs to be None for mode 'write'
    ### Change to 'replace' if the mode is 'a' - append
    sheet_exists = None if md == 'w' else 'replace'

    ### Create writer and write each dataframe to it's own sheet
    ### Since this is a context manager no need to close/save the writer
    with pd.ExcelWriter(fn, mode=md, if_sheet_exists=sheet_exists) as writer:
        for sht_num, dataf in enumerate(dfs, 1):
            dataf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet{sht_num}', index=False, header=False)


### Example dataframes row and column write
df_examples_list = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
### Excel file name
file_name = 'df_file.xlsx'

### Set the ExcelWriter mode based on the existence of the Excel file
if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
    mode = 'w'
else:
    mode = 'a'

### Put dataframes into a list
df_list = []
for data in df_examples_list:
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data))

### Call function with dataframe list, Excel file name and write mode
write_resolution(df_list, file_name, mode)
```